# SUSE Linux DVD writing issue

Tags: suse

I am trying to install SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2 for AMD64/Intel64.
I have downloaded the DVD ISO files from http://download.novell.com/SummaryFree.jsp?buildid=h0AOp5AT-18~

I tried to write the 1st DVD. It is throwing a L-EC Uncorrectable Error. I have used Imgburn for this.
Then i tried to make it bootable using pendrive. That is also failing.

I am able to write the 2nd DVD as well as in pendrive.

Comment: Did you check the checksums of the image file?

Comment: yes.. checked using marxio

Answer (score 0):

Please try using a different DVD Burning software like Astroburn Lite.
http://www.astroburn.com/products/abLite

Comment: Providing alternative tool might be advisable,But provide answer relevant to question

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.  But here the problem is more or less on the DVD burning software/drive used,  not on the DVD ISO files. That is why I suggested an alternative for that .

Answer (score 0):

Try Unetbootin. Create live usb from iso on unetbootin then boot with live usb. After you boot you will see a shortcut on desktop which says Install.

Here is Unetbootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/